# Bar Button does not show in simulator (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I am trying to create a bar button in navigation bar. So I dragged it from object library to the navigation bar, which is in table view controller.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJppE.png)

however, when i run, the bar button does not appear on the simulator.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdMO6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, select the navigation view controller and check the checkbox "Is Initial View Controller" in the attributes inspector.

Comment: thank you so much. I set the tableView controller to be the initial view controller so it did not work.

Comment: Correct. Not only did you have no bar button, you had no bar! You had no navigation controller! You should have been seeing a warning about that in the console, by the way; always watch the console, it tells you useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Select the arrow marked and drag it on to the Navigation Controller, this will make your Navigation Controller the first view. Run it again and now you will see the button.[image][image]